# Add same clickable child to top of every group expandablelistview - android

Tags: java, android, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Okay, so I've been looking far and wide,  I've been able to add the same child item to every group, but I'm unable to get it to respond to clicks.  Right now it's acting like a child header, and I need it to act like the other child items.

Currently my lists are being populated from a HashMap that is located in another file.  Because you cannot add to the middle of a HashMap without completely rebuilding it, I figured the best option was to add the child somewhere when the list is being accessed within the adapter.  I'm just not sure where or how.

As you can see from the getChildView()  I add my repeating child layout (expandedListItemChildHeader), if the position of child is 0.  I also added 1 value to the size of the getChildrenCount().

Here's my adapter code:

```
public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> expandableListTitle;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                   HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
    this.context = context;
    this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
    this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {

    return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .get(expandedListPosition);
}


@Override
public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {

    return expandedListPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //if we're in the first position then add the list_item_header
    if(expandedListPosition == 0)
    {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_header, null);
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItemChildHeader);
        expandedListTextView.setText("All Devices");

    }

    //otherwise add the list_item
    if (expandedListPosition > 0 && expandedListPosition < getChildrenCount(listPosition)) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition - 1);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
    //add a value of one to the size of the count of children per group to make
    //room for the child header

    return (this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
            .size() + 1);
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
    return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.expandableListTitle.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
    return listPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }
    TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    listTitleTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-medium", Typeface.NORMAL));
    listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);

    //Use this conditional to change direction of group indicator icons
    //the ImageView in the xml layout is invisible by default.
    ImageView groupIndicatorView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expand_GroupIndicator);
    if (getChildrenCount(listPosition) == 0 ) {
        groupIndicatorView.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
    }
    else {
        groupIndicatorView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
        groupIndicatorView.setImageResource( isExpanded ? R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_24dp : R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_24dp );
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Following is my expandable list code in my MainActivity which is located in the onCreate() method: (note: the variables listed at the top of the below sample code is outside of the onCreate() method, I just included it for reference.

```
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.navDrawer_userListView);
    expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        //initialize int var
        int previousGroup = 0;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            //this conditional enables only one drop down group to open at a time
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;

            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                            + " List Expanded.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();

        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            v.setSelected(true);

            //Change title on toolbar to match group selection
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + "'s Devices");
            //Change subtitle on toolbar to match item selection
            //must offset child position by 1 to have room for child header
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle((String)expandableListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1));
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                            + " -> "
                            + expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition - 1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Here are my layouts
starting with the list_item_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@null"
            android:id="@+id/toggle_allDevices"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:tint="@color/drawerContent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandedListItemChildHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@drawable/expandable_text_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my list_item.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@null"
            android:id="@+id/deviceTypeIcon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:tint="@color/drawerContent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expandedListItem"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@drawable/expandable_text_selector"
            android:paddingLeft="65dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The list_group.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/drawerContent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/drawerContent"
            android:background="@color/drawerBg"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/expand_GroupIndicator"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:tint="@color/drawerContent"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the snippet of my NavigationView from
the main activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:background="@color/drawerBg"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/drawerContent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/drawerContent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navDrawer_userListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="@color/drawerContent"
            android:textColor="@color/drawerContent"
            android:background="@color/drawerBg"
            android:dividerHeight="@null"
            android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:groupIndicator="@null">
        </ExpandableListView>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: EDIT:  Okay, I'm happy to report I fixed the clickable issue.  I found an obscure post that mentioned if you have a clickable widget like a button or a toggle/switch, it prevents the click event from working.  The simple solution is to put android:focusable="false" in my switch.   The only thing I still need to figure out now it to get the new child to work with the hashmap in terms of matching the index/position with the correct item.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was able to solve the last part of my issue.  it turns out that all I had to do is put a conditional in my onChildClick() method to adjust for which index I was accessing using the following code:

```
//this conditional corrects for our new child header that is added in getChildView()
            String newChildSelect = "";

            if (childPosition == 0) {
                newChildSelect = "All Devices";
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(newChildSelect);
            }
            else
            {
                newChildSelect = expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition - 1);
                //Change subtitle on toolbar to match item selection
                getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle((String)expandableListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition - 1));
            }
```